# UNIX Laravel Artisan File Permission

Tags: laravel, unix, permissions, filesystems, laravel-artisan

We moved a Laravel 5.6 Installation from a Windows to a UNIX Webserver. I manage my laravel over the CLI via Putty and develope from my Windows Machine using a Network Path.

I have a strange Problem and just cant find any solution for this, since im also new to Unix/Linux.

When i run a php artisan create command, it works all just fine. Laravel creates the Migration. But i cant edit the Files on my Windows Machine since i got no Permission.

On older Files that was previously generated on my Windows machine, the Right Window on Windows looks like this:

```
Anyone                               Read
www-data (Unix User\www-data)        Read/Write
www-data (Unix Group\www-data)       Read/Write
```

The rights on the freshly generated Artisan File looks like these. I already added my Unix User to the www-data group.

```
Anyone                               read
pm (Unix User\pm)                    read/write
www-data (Unix Group\www-data)       read
```

I dont know, why the www-data Group dont have read/write Permissions on freshly generated Artisan Files.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to change the `umask` of the user under which artisan is run.

So, go to the root home directory of that user (I guess /home/pm) edit the file ".bashrc" (or create it doesn't exist) and add this line:

```
umask 2
```

which is like "when this user create a new file or directory, make it readable and writable for him or users in his group, but only readable for other users"

More info about `umask` here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html